# html text area with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, textarea

noob here

i got this jquery code that i found on stackoverflow

```
    var maxLines = 2,
    maxLineWidth = 5;

$('#Users_address').bind('change keyup paste drop', function() {
   var value = $(this).val(),
       lines = value.split('\n'),
       linesLength = lines.length;

    if (linesLength > maxLines) {
       lines = lines.slice(0, maxLines);
       linesLength = maxLines;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < linesLength; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > maxLineWidth) {
          lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, maxLineWidth);  
        } 
    }

    $(this).val(lines.join('\n'));
});
```

how would i use this with a text area??

Comment: to get only 5 characters per line and 2 lines max, from the text area.

Comment: In the future you should post attempts that you have made on your own to solve your problems, especially when dealing with snippets of code that you have received from other sources. If you explain what you have tried, we can help explain why it didn't work and help you get on the right track. In the end, you'll learn more this way.

Comment: replace Users_address with your textarea id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your textarea an `id`:

```
<textarea id="Users_address"></textarea>
```

And load your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxLines = 2,
    maxLineWidth = 5;

    $('#Users_address').bind('change keyup paste drop', function() {
       var value = $(this).val(),
           lines = value.split('\n'),
           linesLength = lines.length;

        if (linesLength > maxLines) {
           lines = lines.slice(0, maxLines);
           linesLength = maxLines;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < linesLength; i++) {
            if (lines[i].length > maxLineWidth) {
              lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, maxLineWidth);  
            } 
        }

        $(this).val(lines.join('\n'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your text area id 'Users_address' or change that '#Users_address' to '#{textarea-id}' replacing the stuff in the brackets with your text area id, then it will work with your text area.